# Change MeshBasicMaterial opacity dynamically

Tags: javascript, three.js

```
<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
          "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@v0.162.0/build/three.module.js",
          "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@v0.162.0/examples/jsm/"
        }
    }
</script>

<script type="module">
    import * as THREE from 'three';

    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    camera.position.z = 10;
    camera.position.x = -5;

    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 2, 2, 2 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
    const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( cube );
     
    material.opacity = 0.2;
    material.transparent = true;

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }
    animate();
</script>
```

Above works and opacity of cube is changing, but if move `material` updating into setTimeout function, like:

```
// material.opacity = 0.2;
// material.transparent = true;
var tmout = function() {
    material.opacity = 0.2;
    material.transparent = true;
}
setTimeout(tmout, 1000 );
```

Then opacity is not changing. Why `material` is not changing inside setTimeout? what is incorrect here?

Comment: It's likely because of the "module" space. so, "material.opacity" is not document.material.opacity, but document.module.material.opacity , so it's setting a property on an incorrect object.  try using an arrow function to encapsulate context of this var.

Answer (score 1):

Using arrow function to capture context of this, from within calling module.
¯\*(ツ)*/¯

```js
import * as THREE from 'three';
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 10;
camera.position.x = -5;
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2, 2);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x00ff00
});
const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

scene.add(cube);
material.opacity = 1;
material.transparent = true;


function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  setTimeout(() => {
      this.material.opacity = 0.2;
      this.material.transparent = true;
    },
    1000);
}
animate();
```

Comment: Thanks, played with this and noticed that if initialize material  with transparent property, like: `var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
     color: 0x00ff00,
     transparent: true
   });` 
Then usual function works too (need to update only opacity):
    `var tmout = function() {
       material.opacity = 0.2;
   }
   setTimeout(tmout, 1000 );`

Comment: I'm glad I could help shake this free for ya!